# Showing Related Posts Manually (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a custom post type in my wordpress website under which we publish our reports. Here's a sample report page -

goo.gl/hqVFJ2

See the report name. The report name has a specific format which is "Region" Report Topic "Market"

For each topic we have 5 regional variants, which are as follow:

Global
North America
Europe
Asia Paciic
LAMEA
Our requirement is, when someone opens any one of the variant the other 4 should appear under the similar reports section. For that matter I used Contextual Related Posts plugin which is not able to meet the requirement 100% and in fact to the contrary making the site heavy. I was trying to figure out if there can be a way to achieve this with a custom code.

I found a code snippet but that shows similar posts as per the tags.

Here's the code of the report page:

```
<h1 itemprop="headline" class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?> </h1>
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cc_price', true) !== '') { ?><span



            class="price_meta">



            <span class="price_left"></span><span class="price_center"><?php



                if (cc_get_option('cc_currency') != '') {



                    echo cc_get_option('cc_currency');



                } else {



                    echo get_option('currency_symbol');



                }



                echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cc_price', true);



                ?></span><span class="price_right"></span></span> <?php } ?>



        <ul class="post_meta">



            <li class="estimate"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'publish_date_new',true); ?><time class="dt-published" datetime="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'publish_date_new',true); ?>"></time></li>



            <li class="cate"><?php printf(IN . '&nbsp;' . '%s', $taxonomies); ?></li>



            <li itemprop="author" class="author p-author h-card">By <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'published_by_new',true); ?>



                </li>
```

Comment: is region post-format? Or  do you have any thing common with your posts? I mean post_meta or tags or categories?

Comment: Only thing in common is the report's topic. Vlaoff just suggested below to create a custom field in order to have a similar attribute.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is add a custom field to specify the Unique Id of the report.
Then display all posts with that Unique Id (except the one the user is on)

You can use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/) to create the custom field.

Then your hook would look something like

```
<?php

   $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
    'meta_key' => 'report_unique_id',
    'meta_value' => the_field('report_unique_id'),
    'post__not_in' => get_the_ID(),
));

if($posts)
{
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
     /* Your related Post */ 
    }
}

?>
```